# UITabBar Size increased on iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-x

I am facing the issue that my tabbar is stretched on the new iPhone X.
I am using a regular UITabBarController with no further styling for height etc. I want it to be like the iPhone 8 picture so placed against the bottom of the view and not stretched like it is at this moment.

Is this easy?

iPhone X

[image: UITabBarController iPhone X]

iPhone 8

[image: UITabBarController iPhone 8]

Comment: It should look the same automatically. The only reason there should be a space is for the bottom line to indicate that users can swipe up to go to the home screen. Can you give more context on what you view looks like and how your tab bar controller is setup.

Comment: try with safe layout guide and see. I must work

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  I had the same problem with a tabBarController created in a window - all programmatically, that is no XIB.  I solved it by setting the window.frame to a height equal to the UIScreen height plus the window.safeAreaInserts.bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of the lack of home button on the X its done like that to give the User some room for the upward swipe gesture to get to the home page (if you were able to lower it more you'd be screwing over your iPhone X users)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. 34 pixels from bottom are reserved for gesture. If you want do like on iPhone 8, that users who use your app will have inconvenience.

Comment: I require using 35 pixels from the bottom.